# Stopping the VerticalHeader to update on QTableview

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtableview

I am implementing a QTableview to display a huge amount of data. Instead of showing all at once, I am showing 10000 rows and dynamically adding and subtracting the data from the table. I am facing a problem when deleting the upper rows; the vertical header gets updated, and row numbers get changed. Any way to stop the vertical header from updating.

```
bool flag = 0;
int last_row = 1000;
int top_row = 0;
int margin = 30;
void DataTable::verticalScrollbarAction(int action) {
    if(((this->rowAt(0)) - margin) < top_row && flag == 1)
    {
        this->getTableModel()->GetData(top_row-101, top_row-1, 0);
        this->getTableModel()->removeRows(last_row -101, last_row -1);
        last_row -= 100;
        top_row -= 100;
    }
    else if ((this->rowAt(this->height()) + margin) > last_row)
    {
        flag = 1;
        this->getTableModel()->GetData(last_row, last_row+100, 1);
        this->getTableModel()->removeRows(0, 100);
        last_row += 100;
        top_row += 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to provide an MRE. It is much easier and less risky to go from there as many things could go wrong without seeing the details.

Answer (score 0):

The below answer is just my guess.
May be you can try a bit on it.

Get the vertical header object

```
QHeaderView *pHeaderView = yourTableView->verticalHeader();
```

Now go through the below documentation `defaultSectionSize` of `QHeaderView`

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qheaderview.html#defaultSectionSize-prop

> By default, the value of this property is style dependent. Thus, when
> the style changes, this property updates from it. Calling
> setDefaultSectionSize() stops the updates, calling
> resetDefaultSectionSize() will restore default behavior.

May be what you can do is first call

```
pHeaderView->setDefaultSectionSize(QHeaderView::Fixed);
```

After you are done with your business, you can call below to restore default behavior.

```
pHeaderView->resetDefaultSectionSize();
```